# Cross domain authentication with Ion_auth for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a website built on Codeigniter with Ion_auth for authentication.

I'm now building a new site with PyroCMS and would like users to be logged into PyroCMS when they're logged into my original site.

What's the best way to check the session or cookie in the second Codeigniter site?

Comment: Are they under the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [appstucco](http://www.appstucco.com/products). It basically replaces your pyrocms users module with a custom version so that you can use one ldap server for multiple sites.

For official pyrocms blog post about appsutcco: http://www.pyrocms.com/blog/2012/05/appstucco-making-cool-addons